# Is there a way to pass sqlhost name dynamically in Docketfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

We have created a sqlhost file in gitrepo along with dockerfile, kubernetes yaml file and jenkinsfile,each time I have to manually add entry in sqlhost file which later dockerfile takes the value from sqlhost
Is there a way from jenkins which can pass value as a parameter to dockefile and then build dockefile

Comment: What does this file look like; what consumes it?  In general you should avoid trying to pass in specific host names during the `docker build` step, it's better to use a mechanism like environment variables to make them available at run time (and not need to rebuild the image just because you deployed to somewhere different).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `ARG`? Please refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ARG` or an `ENV` instruction to specify variables that are needed to be available to the Dockerfile

**ARG**: Sample dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG SQLHOST
```

Here  you can see the SQLHOST Argument is provided in dockerfile, and while buiding specify as

```
$ docker build --build-arg SQLHOST=prod-vm.example.com .
```

also you can use specify same in Jenkins configuration.

**ENV**: Sample dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV SQLHOST defaultHost
```

Here  you can see the SQLHOST Environment variable is provided in dockerfile, and while buiding specify as

```
$ set SQLHOST=prod-vm.example.com; docker build .
```

also you can use specify same in Jenkins configuration.